# Which versions of ASP.NET gets installed with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Does Visual Studio 2010 install of ASP.NET 2.0, ASP.NET 3.5, and ASP.NET 4.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 comes with asp.net 2.0,3.5 and 4.0.
So if you have an existing asp.net 2.0 site for example then you can open and run this in vs2010 (vs 2010 will prompt you when you click the original solution that in order to run in vs2010 you need to upgrade the solution,this is all very straight forward). Similarly if you have an existing asp.net 3.5 site.

Also if you wish to start creating a new asp.net site and wish to use the 2.0 framework or 3.5 etc rather than the 4.0 framework then you can just select the desired version.